# loop to perform a random amount of times

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a random number which I'll call x, and then generate x amount of numbers that are also random. I'm trying a for loop to no avail. There's more to the assignment but I feel like I'm at a roadblock till I figure this out.

My code:

```
def main():
    import random
    numbers_file=open('numbers.txt','w')
    file_size = random.randint(4,7)

    for x in range(file_size):
        x = random.randint(5,19)
        numbers_file.write(str(x))



    print (file_size)   
    print (x)

main()
```

The print commands at the bottom are only there to test it as I need to write the random numbers to a file afterward.

edit: So that works but now I have to create a program to read the file I created, It needs to be in a format I can't figure out
ex. 5 7 5 11 8 6
the total is 42

what I have

```
def main():
    number_file = open('numbers.txt','r')
    number = (number_file.readline())
    print(number,)
    number_file.close()

main()
```

Comment: What's not working, specifically? This looks like it should work. I just tried it on my machine and it worked, AFAIK.

Comment: Your print commands don't appear to be indented properly, so they will only be executed after the for loop.

Comment: So... how about telling us what's wrong. It prints the numbers to a file. They look kinda weird because you don't add any separators like white space or line feeds. But the values are there.

Comment: it did work with some tweaking. Now im stuck trying to figure out how to create a program that reads that file and outputs like this

Comment: 5 7 6 4 5 4   total is x

Comment: You don't seem too keen on giving us hints. What is the format you ended up with? is it a single line of space-separated integers? You could `sum(int(i) for i in open('numbers.txt').readline().strip().split(' '))`.

Comment: Don't start writing to a file until you know you have good data to write.  Especially do not post file-writing code here.  Also, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: oh Im not supposed to put filewriting code here?